# Angularjs huge page load time " X items hidden by filters"

Tags: angularjs

[image]So I have a page on my app, that has an `ng-repeat` that loads a list of about 1080 elements. Before the page is done loading (which takes about 10 seconds!) there is some text in the DOM editor that says " X items hidden by filters" (in my case, x = 1129).

The number starts at 0, and goes up to 1129, taking a few seconds to do this. **What is this "hidden by filters" thing?** And since im not filtering anything on my page, what is it even for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get more details by clicking "Info" and selecting "Verbose" in the same line ...

[image]